# How To Backup "crontab -e" Files?

Tags: linux, backup, cron, backup-restoration

I want to do a ***complete*** server backup.

I already have my backup script copying all of the html/php files for the web app, and the mysql databases, placing them into a .tar.gz file.

How can I add the crontab files to that backup?

Whenever I save the crontab, it goes to /tmp folder.. and when I check that folder immediately afterwards, it is empty.

Comment: Just a though, may versions of cron allow root to place the jobs in `/etc/cron.d/`, I generally prefer that instead, since my /etc folder is backed up, and tracked in a VCS.

Comment: related: ["What I can I do to make the transition to some new computer hardware safe and smooth?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/what-i-can-i-do-to-make-the-transition-to-some-new-computer-hardware-safe-and-sm).

Comment: With regard to your username, sorry to take away your '666' upvote count -but I found the post useful. ;)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could just backup the entire `/var/spool/cron` directory. It contains all crontabs for all users.

Answer (score 29):

You can periodically run `crontab -l > my_crontab.backup` to backup the crontab into file.

Answer (score 12):

just backup the file `/var/spool/cron/USER_NAME`

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 at least, the relevant files are in the directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: @KennyEvitt and you must be the root to access it `sudo -i`

Answer (score 5):

I made my backup into a cron job.

```
0 9 * * * crontab -l | gzip > /backups/'crontab-'$(date +"\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S")'.gz'
```

Comment: Seriously, you gzip it? Is that even reducing the file size?